# Function adds an unwanted line

Tags: python, function

```
class board:
  def __init__(self, length, height, letter):
    self.layout = ((' ' + letter) * length + ' \n') * height
    self.length = length
    self.height = height
    self.objects = {}

  def draw(self, length=None, height=None, letter=None, double=False, show=True):
    #adds a line every time
    if length == None or height == None or letter == None:
      print(self.layout)
    else:
      if letter != '':
        letter = letter[0]
      layout = self.layout.split('\n')[:-1]
      if layout[0] == '':
        layout = layout[1:]
      old = ''
      for num in range(height):
        if num != height:
          num = num - 1
          old = old + layout[num] + '\n'
      new = old
      num = length * 2
      n = 0
      old = ''
      for item in layout[height]:
        n = n + 1
        if n == num:
          old_block = item
          old = old + letter
        else:
          old = old + item
      string = new + old + '\n'
      print(len(layout[height-1:len(layout) -1]))
      print(len(layout))
      string = string + '\n'.join(layout[height-1:len(layout) -1]) + '\n'
      self.layout = string
      self.objects[letter] = (length, height, old_block)
      if show:
        if double:
          print(string.replace(' ', '  '))
        else:
          print(string)
```

I am trying to create a module which a function that draws a board and you can also add an object at a specific space, but sadly my function called draw adds an unwanted line.

I would be very grateful if you could help me!

Comment: Please update your question with example outputs. Please include the current behaviour of your code, plus your desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.layout = (((' ' + letter) * length + ' \n') * height)[:-2]
```

also

```
  self.objects[letter] = (length, height, old_block)
  string = string[:-2]
  if show:
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. I appreciate it.